# How can I execute SQL files stored in Github?

Tags: bash, azure, github, scripting, azure-sql-database

I have a nice bash script that uses `az cli` to generate an Azure SQL Server (`az sql server create`) and SQL database (`az sql db create`).

I'd like to populate the database with tables and columns I have defined in a series of `.sql` files stored in Github.

**Example file:**

- Filename: `TST_HDR.sql`
- File contents:

```sql
-- Create a new table called 'TEST_HDR' in schema 'dbo'
-- Drop the table if it already exists
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TEST_HDR', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.TEST_HDR
GO
-- Create the table in the specified schema
CREATE TABLE dbo.TEST_HDR
(
    tstID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    tstGUID [NVARCHAR](50),
    tstComments [NVARCHAR](2000),
    tstHdrCreated DATETIME2,
    tstHdrCreatedBy [NVARCHAR](255),
    tstHdrLastUpdated DATETIME2,
    tstHdrLastUpdatedBy [NVARCHAR](255),
    tstHdrDeleted [NVARCHAR](3),
    tstHdrDeletedBy [NVARCHAR](255),
    tstHdrVersionNum INT
);
GO
```

**Which bash (or other scripting) commands do I use to get these files from Github and execute them against the SQL database?**

Comment: git clone ..... mysql ...... < *.sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have [sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) installed:

```sh
tmp=$(mktemp) && \
curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/path/to/your/TST_HDR.sql > ${tmp} && \
sqlcmd -S <servername>.database.windows.net -d <database> -U <user> -P <password> -i ${tmp}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is great. How would you handle multiple .sql files in this case?

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir (create directory)
cd (to the directory created, for the Github repository)
git clone (The address to the repository where your sql file is located)
```

Make sure the ports are accessible on the pc you are connecting from and on the server you are connecting to.

```
sqlcmd -d (database) -i (filepath to the sql file, in the git repository) -P (password) -S (servername).database.windows.net -U (user)
```

Comment: This is great. I was unaware of `sqlcmd`. How is this handled for multiple sql files? Would I need a loop of some kind or just repeat the command shown?

Comment: One way is to create a script which would run each of the .SQL files. This article should help you, https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1543/using-sqlcmd-to-execute-multiple-sql-server-scripts/